# Change `itertools.product` iteration order

Tags: python, python-itertools

Given some iterables, `itertools.product` iterates from back to front, trying all choices of the last iterable before advancing the second-to-last iterable, and trying all choices of the last two iterables before advancing the third-to-last iterable, etc. For instance,

```
>>> list(itertools.product([2,1,0],['b','c','a']))
[(2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c'), (0, 'a')]
```

I would like to iterate over the product in a different manner: the order the tuples should be produced is by the sum of the indices of the elements they contain, i.e., before producing a tuple whose elements' indices in their respective iterables sum to k, produce all tuples whose elements' indices in their respective iterables sum to k-1. For example, after producing the tuple containing the first element (index 0) of every iterable, the next tuples produced should each contain the second element from a single iterable and the first from the rest; after that, the tuples produced should contain the third element from one tuple or the second element from two tuples, etc. Using the above example,

```
>>> my_product([2,1,0],['b','c','a'])
[(2, 'b'),                     # element 0 from both iterables
 (2, 'c'), (1, 'b'),           # elements 0,1 and 1,0 (sums to 1)
 (2, 'a'), (1, 'c'), (0, 'b'), # elements 0,2 and 1,1 and 2,0 (sums to 2)
 (1, 'a'), (0, 'c'),           # elements 1,2 and 2,1 (sums to 3)
 (0, 'a')]                     # elements 2,2 (sums to 4)
```

Comment: I think the answers aren't quite understanding your requirement. Could you include a sample with a non-increasing list?

Comment: Are you dealing with sequences small enough that the result of `product()` will comfortably fit in memory?

Comment: @Robᵩ my solution does not rely on the items being numeric or increasing whatsoever

Comment: @fferri - Yes. I unfairly maligned your answer along with the others. *Mea cupla.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this with sorting:

```
def my_product(*args):
    return [tuple(i[1] for i in p) for p in
        sorted(itertools.product(*map(enumerate, args)),
            key=lambda x: (sum(y[0] for y in x), x))]
```

Test:

```
>>> my_product([0,1,2],[3,4,5])
[(0, 3), 
 (0, 4), (1, 3), 
 (0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), 
 (1, 5), (2, 4), 
 (2, 5)]
```

works also with non-sorted, non-numeric items:

```
>>> my_product(['s0','b1','k2'],['z3','a4','c5'])
[('s0', 'z3'), 
 ('s0', 'a4'), ('b1', 'z3'), 
 ('s0', 'c5'), ('b1', 'a4'), ('k2', 'z3'), 
 ('b1', 'c5'), ('k2', 'a4'), 
 ('k2', 'c5')]
```

```
>>> my_product([2,1,0],['b','c','a'])
[(2, 'b'), 
 (2, 'c'), (1, 'b'), 
 (2, 'a'), (1, 'c'), (0, 'b'), 
 (1, 'a'), (0, 'c'), 
 (0, 'a')]
```

and with multiple args:

```
>>> my_product([2,1,0],['b','c','a'],['x','y','z'])
[(2, 'b', 'x'), 
 (2, 'b', 'y'), (2, 'c', 'x'), (1, 'b', 'x'), 
 (2, 'b', 'z'), (2, 'c', 'y'), (2, 'a', 'x'), (1, 'b', 'y'), (1, 'c', 'x'), (0, 'b', 'x'), 
 (2, 'c', 'z'), (2, 'a', 'y'), (1, 'b', 'z'), (1, 'c', 'y'), (1, 'a', 'x'), (0, 'b', 'y'), (0, 'c', 'x'), 
 (2, 'a', 'z'), (1, 'c', 'z'), (1, 'a', 'y'), (0, 'b', 'z'), (0, 'c', 'y'), (0, 'a', 'x'), 
 (1, 'a', 'z'), (0, 'c', 'z'), (0, 'a', 'y'),
 (0, 'a', 'z')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you'll need to check that sum why don' you just use sort:

```
def my_product(*args):
    return list(sorted(itertools.product(*args), key=lambda x: (sum(x), x)))
```

Comment: It's a nice idea, but I will not necessarily be using this on lists of ints, and even if I were those lists might not be sorted. Is there a way to do this based on the indices?

Comment: @BallpointBen This matches your input-output case, could you maybe edit the question to match your actual needs or even propose another question?

Comment: Edited to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to sorting, this solution makes multiple passes over the result of `itertools.product()`.

Note that it uses the same decorate-manipulate-undecorate pattern that other answers use.

```
import itertools

# TESTED on Python3
def my_product(*args):
    args = [list(enumerate(arg)) for arg in args]
    for sum_indexes in range(sum(len(item) for item in args)):
        for partial in itertools.product(*args):
            indexes, values = zip(*partial)
            if sum(indexes) == sum_indexes:
                yield values

assert list(my_product([2,1,0],['b','c','a'])) == [
    (2, 'b'),                     # element 0 from both iterables
    (2, 'c'), (1, 'b'),           # elements 0,1 and 1,0 (sums to 1)
    (2, 'a'), (1, 'c'), (0, 'b'), # elements 0,2 and 1,1 and 2,0 (sums to 2)
    (1, 'a'), (0, 'c'),           # elements 1,2 and 2,1 (sums to 3)
    (0, 'a')]
```